# Finding out email used to create YouTube account

Tags: youtube

I am the Communications Manager of an NGO and I would like to delete this YouTube Channel that was created by a former employee: https://www.youtube.com/user/wilpfgeneva

I do not know which email address was used to create that account and I have already tried all possible email recovery solutions.

The account is not associated to Google+ so I cannot send a message on YouTube.

How can I find out which email address was used to open such channel? Is there anything similar to Google "site share request"http://sitesguide.pjrprojects.co.uk/google-sites/how-tos/user-access-assist?

That is how I managed to get access to an old website (again created by a former employee), which I need to close down.

Answer (score 2):

For privacy reasons, you cannot find out the email address used.

As a workaround, If you want to close down a channel you have lost access to, you can flag the videos the channel uploaded as copyright infringement.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at the channel in question and I'm sorry to say it is not possible for you to find the email address which created the account or for you to "shut it down" without a court order.
This is a pre-2014 account without a confirmed name, and with maximum privacy settings enabled which hide their name and their email. 
You can't find out who started the channel but you can try to close it down, by flagging their videos if they violate [YouTube community guidelines](https://www.youtube.com/yt/policyandsafety/en-GB/communityguidelines.html). Unfortunately in your specific case this seems to be an act of whistleblowing and doesn't seem to violate and of the rules.

Your only option is to take the individual to court and sue for some form of defamation, and as part of that have the court force them to take it down.

Comment: @pnuts I believed that OP wanted to take this other guy to court not the other way around.

Comment: @pnuts "The channel was created by a former employee" of my organisation... If OP knows the other guy used to work for OP I'd hope he knows who he is